# De Giorgi's structure theorem for reduced boundary - why compact submanifolds?

Tags: geometric-measure-theory

De Giorgi's structure theorem states the following (Theorem 15.9 from Maggi's *Sets of Finite Perimeter and Geometric Variational Problems*, or e.g. Theorem 4.3 of Giusti's *Minimal Surfaces and Functions of Bounded Variation*).

---

If $E$ is a set of locally finite perimeter in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then [...] there exist countably many $C^1$ hypersurfaces $M_h$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, **compact** sets $K_h \subset M_h$, and a Borel set $S$ with $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(F)=0$, such that
$$\partial^* E=F \cup \bigcup_{h \in \mathbb{N}} K_h.$$

---

I don't understand how the sets $K_h$ can be taken to be compact if $E$ has vertices.
For example, the reduced boundary of a square consists of the square's boundary minus the square's four vertices (Maggi's Example 15.4). How can we write that set as a union of compact submanifolds and a set of measure zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out. The theorem only requires a *countable* union of compact sets. We can take a sequence of compact subsets of the form $K_h:=\{x \in \partial E : \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial E \backslash \partial^* E)\ge\frac{1}{h}\}$.